# how to add css class to simple_form_for f.association field. to use selectize-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selectize.js

### Form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.association :categories, input_html: { id: 'selectized'}  %>
</div>
```

### .coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
 $('#selectized').selectize
 delimiter: ','
 persist: false
 create: (input) ->
  {
 value: input
 text: input
  }
```

### inspect element

The above code does not work

Answer (score 4):

The question is how to add `class` but you example tries to use an `id`, either way that's not going to work for `f.association`

You can add `class` or `id` by passing `input_html`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.association :categories, input_html: { id: 'your_id', class: 'your_class' }  %>
</div>
```